# When i switch from preview to render I can see through my object

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing

My object looks good in Material preview mode, but when i switch to render I can see through it. Do you know where could be the problem?
[image]

[image]

Comment: do you mind sharing your .blend file with me so I can take a closer look?

Comment: Not at all. Here is dropbox link for that file.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0w2wrmtd06y1kqj/eeej2.blend?dl=0

Comment: @VáclavMusil, the textures are not packed in the blend file: so we can't see the same result. I presume though that they are reflexion from the back surface that are not visible if not rendered with Cycles.

Comment: Yes when i changed texture it helped, but I dont uderstand why. This is my first try using textures and rendering.

Comment: Hello :). @lemon is right, those are simply reflections (just tested it). The reason is physics - objects viewed from a *very* shallow angle are rather reflective (especially metal).